# If statement involving "is not empty" in smarty template?

Tags: smarty

How do I do this in a Smarty template:

If {contact.supplemental_address_1} is not empty 
then

{contact.supplemental_address_1}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{capture assign=temp}{contact.supplemental_address_1}{/capture} {if $temp ne ""} {$temp}
{/if}
```

is what I do. I got the idea from the source referenced above. You also need to ensure that smarty is turned on in civicrm.settings.php

Comment: Just found that all this is now very nicely set out in the latest version of the User Guide at https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/tokens-and-mail-merge/

Answer (score 1):

Found a whole bunch of examples - including an isset one in Example 7.15

https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.if.tpl

Answer (score 1):

A little cleaner approach

```
{if $contact.supplemental_address_1}{contact.supplemental_address_1}{/if}
```

Comment: Are you sure about this? It doesn't work for me. Fine if the field is null, but it doesn't print if it is none null. I'm on CiviCRM 4.7.24 and WordPress 4.9 The documentation suggests my solution below.

Comment: Yes. This works in Civi 4.7.20 + WordPress 4.8 and also Civi 4.6.10 + Drupal 7.41 (with smarty turned on of course). I also tested with a few other contact variables include the first_name token listed in the example. They all worked when I used the $variable in the if statement. I hadn't taken an in-depth look at the user guide, I've used the shorter if logic based on samples in the default contribution receipt text. I can't speak to why the user guide recommends assigning an existing contact token first, that's above my pay grade ;)

Comment: Will try again!

Comment: Tried again very carefully and it still doesn't work. But as I have my own less elegant solution I'm not going to spend more time on it.

Comment: Looks nice but didn't quite work

Comment: As a follow up, apologies I did not test for this distinction before - this works in sending an email (for me) but not print to PDF templates. For print to PDF I had to do the assign method as well.